# Rubik's Cube Scramble Generator algorithm

Tags: c++

I've been recently working on a project which includes a Rubik's Cube scramble generator. Basically the program should generate and display random cube notations so that the user can follow each move and have a fairly scrambled cube. Notations include "R" for turning the right layer , "L" for turning the left layer, "F" for turning front layer, "D" for down, "U" for up and "B" for back. And so you have a total of 6 sides "R, L, U, D, F, B". The appostrophe after any of these notations means moving that layer counter clockwise and "2" means moving that layer twice. The problem is you can't have the same notation be repeated next to each other like "R, R" as it would be the same as "R2", nor you can have "R, R' " next to each other as they would cancel each other out. My solution to this was making a 2 dimensional array for storing the 3 groups of notations for every type.

```
string notation_group[row][column] = { { "R ", "L ", "F ", "B ", "U ", "D " },
    {"R' ", "L' ", "F' ", "B' ", "U' ", "D' "}, { "R2", "L2", "F2", "B2", "U2", "D2"} };
```

This means that whenever the program picks a random column from any of these groups, the program has to prevent the next generated notation from choosing the same column in any other group. So let's say if the program picks the first element of the first group "R", then for the next iteration it can choose any notation except "R", "R' " and "R2", all of which belong to the first column of their respective groups. So all the program has to do is not to pick that column during the next iteration.

I used a "temp" variable to keep in mind the current randomly generated notation and compare it to the next one, and generating a new one whenever those are equal.

```
int temp;

            scrambled_notation[i] = notation_group[pickGroup][pickColumn];

            temp = pickColumn;

            pickColumn = 0 + rand() % 6;

            while (temp == pickColumn) {
                pickColumn = 0 + rand() % 6;
            }
```

It does work but there is still another problem, whenever you have something like "R, L" or "R, L', R" be repeated multiple times next to each other they would again cancel each other out leaving no affect on the cube. Is there any idea for how can I prevent two of the opposing sides being repeated next to each other for more than once? I would greatly appreciate the help.

```
    void initScramble(const int, string[][6], string[]);

int main() {

    srand(time(0));

    const int row = 3, column = 6;
    string notation_group[row][column] = { { "R", "L", "F", "B", "U", "D" },
    {"R'", "L'", "F'", "B'", "U'", "D'"}, { "R2", "L2", "F2", "B2", "U2", "D2"} };

    const int scrambleSize = 22;
    string scrambled_notation[scrambleSize];

    cout << "SCRAMBLE: " << endl;

    initScramble(scrambleSize, notation_group, scrambled_notation);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void initScramble(const int scrambleSize, string notation_group[][6], string scrambled_notation[]) {

    int pickColumn = 0 + rand() % 6;

    while (true) {

        cin.get();

        for (int i = 0; i < scrambleSize; i++) {

            int pickGroup = 0 + rand() % 3;

            int temp;

            scrambled_notation[i] = notation_group[pickGroup][pickColumn];

            temp = pickColumn;

            pickColumn = 0 + rand() % 6;

            while (temp == pickColumn) {
                pickColumn = 0 + rand() % 6;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < scrambleSize; i++) {
            cout << scrambled_notation[i] << "  ";
        }
        cin.get();
        system("CLS");
    }

}
```

Comment: You could create a hash function describing the state of the cube and store every new state in a cache/blacklist (like an `unordered_set` of these hash values). For every move you are about to do, check if it would result in a state you've had before, if it would, reject that move and try another one.

Comment: @TedLyngmo it does not have to be a hash, actual state can be encoded in pretty short format.

Comment: One 66 bit (I guess 128 bits would have to be used) integer is enough to describe all possible 43252003274489856000 states so any function that takes a cube and turns it into a unique number that could be used to get the cube back would work. As long as it's bijective, it will work, but I suspect that you'd actually want to create a hash function to replace the `size_t` hashes normally used or otherwise you'd get a hash on your 128 bit number.

Comment: You also could go for splitting by axis. Put all U/D/E turns in one array, then L/R/M in a second and F/B/S moves in a third array... If you want to also have shuffles like "U L2 R' U" you need also multi-moves for one axis in the array. Not using slices, you have 3x 6 moves per array in simple and 3x 6+9 four multi. Simplest would be to pick an axis (differs from last axis) then run a chance (like 0.8/0.2) to do one or two moves over that axis (2 moves use opposing sides). have your array like `{{R,R2,R',L,L2,L'},[U...` now either run random [1 to 6] or [[1 to 3] AND [4 to 6]]....

Answer (score 2):

You have to look for the last two moves as long as they are commutative. If not, then you only check for the last move. This is simplified by the fact that each pair of columns are commutative:

```
void initScramble(const int scrambleSize, string notation_group[][6], string scrambled_notation[]) {
    while (true) {
        int lastColumn = 7; // Invalid columns
        int beforeLastColumn = 7;

        cin.get();

        for (int i = 0; i < scrambleSize; i++) {
            int pickGroup = 0 + rand() % 3;
            int pickColumn = 0 + rand() % 6;
            bool isCommutative = (lastColumn / 2) == (beforeLastColumn / 2);

            while (pickColumn == lastColumn || isCommutative && pickColumn == beforeLastColumn) {
                pickColumn = 0 + rand() % 6;
            }

            scrambled_notation[i] = notation_group[pickGroup][pickColumn];
            beforeLastColumn = lastColumn;
            lastColumn = pickColumn;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < scrambleSize; i++) {
            cout << scrambled_notation[i] << "  ";
        }
        cin.get();
        system("CLS");
    }
}
```

You don't have to look further since you can have only 2 commutative consecutive moves following your rules of scrambling. For example, 'L,R,L' and 'L,R,R' will be discarded, and thus, 3 commutative moves will never be generated.

Answer (score 0):

First, I use boolean to input what moves that should be cancelled

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

bool cancelMove(string first, string second){
    return(
            first + second == "RL" ||
            first + second == "LR" ||
            first + second == "UD" ||
            first + second == "DU" ||
            first + second == "FB" ||
            first + second == "BF"
        );
    }
```

and then I make two elements which is move and befTurn, move is for the current notation and befTurn is for the notation before the current one. Then I use switches to generate the notation counterclockwise (') and 180 degrees turn ( 2).

```
void scrambler(int enter, string notation[]){

    string move;
    string befTurn;

    for(int x = 0; x < enter; x++){

        do{
            int turns = rand() % 6;
            move = notation[turns];
        }while(move == befTurn || cancelMove(move, befTurn));

        befTurn = move;

        int mod = rand() % 3 + 1;
        switch(mod){
            case 1 :
            cout << move << " ";
            break;

            case 2 :
            cout << move << "2 ";
            break;

            case 3 : 
            cout << move << "' ";
            break;
        }

    }

}
```

then print it all out...

```
int main(){

    srand(time(0));
    
    string notation[] = {"U", "F", "R", "L", "D", "B"};
    int enter;

    cout << "Please enter the number of moves : ";
    cin >> enter;

    scrambler(enter, notation);

    return 0;
}
```